# Error when defining an object in a React Native component class

Tags: react-native

I'm keep getting the following error when executing the React Native code below.

[Link to Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXfOf.png)

I've tried various ways to define the actionEnum object but nothing seems to work. Please help!

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  AsyncStorage
} from "react-native";

class AddItem extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Add item"
  };

  static actionEnum = {
    init: 1,
    add: 2,
    update: 3,
    delete: 4,
    set: 5
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setStateHandler(this.actionEnum.add);
  }
```

.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have static *variables*, only [static *methods*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). You can work around this by exporting your enum object from your module instead of making it part of your class, but if you really need it to be part of your class you can use a [`get` accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
class AddItem extends React.Component {
  static get navigationOptions() {
    return {
      title: "Add item"
    };
  }

  static get actionEnum() {
    return {
      init: 1,
      add: 2,
      update: 3,
      delete: 4,
      set: 5
    };
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setStateHandler(this.actionEnum.add);
  }
```

Comment: the es6 spec does... which is used by React-native

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#_constructor-static-methods-prototype-methods

Comment: Actually, the ES6 spec only defines static methods, not static data properties (variables).

"For the sake of finishing ES6 classes in time, they were deliberately designed to be “maximally minimal”. That’s why you can currently only create static methods, getters, and setters, but not static data properties."

From your own link.

Comment: Trying to say `static name = value` where `value` is not a function within a class usually leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: The syntax `static name = value` for arbitrary data is expected to be a part of ES7+. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers